# Retrieving and rendering data from Firebase in Angular

Tags: angularjs, firebase

I am using Angular to add data (Users and their Orders) to Firebase.

Below is the DB structure in Firebase.

[Firebase DB Structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1HiqG.png)

Below is the code I am using to RETRIEVE all the Orders for a particular User from Firebase.

```
var orddataref = fbref.child("profile").child($scope.cart.userkey).child("orders");
orddataref.on("child_added", function(snap) {
    ordersRef.child(snap.key()).once("value", function(snapshot) {
      $scope.odata = snapshot.val();
      $scope.apply();
    });
});
```

Below is the code I am using to RENDER in my HTML.

```
<div ng-repeat="order in odata">
      <div> Order Address : {{order.address}}</div>
      <div> Deliverynotes : {{order.deliverynotes}}</div>
      <div> Total Amount : {{order.totalamount}}</div>
            <ion-item class ="item" ng-repeat="item in order.items">
                <div> Item SKU : {{item.sku}}</div>
                <div> Price : {{item.price}}</div>
                <div> Quantity : {{item.quantity}}</div>
            </ion-item>
 </div>
```

It is getting only current item back and not all the orders (including previous orders).
Can anyone suggest where I am going wrong? Any help is appreciated very much.

**Edited after Frank's suggestion**
Frank, I put a breakpoint on the line `$scope.odata = snapshot.val();`  It is just having the current order as below.

```
{"address":"Auckland, New Zealand","deliverynotes":"At door","items":[{"price":3,"quantity":2,"sku":"1002"},{"price":6.5,"quantity":3,"sku":"2002"}],"totalamount":25.5}
```

So I put a logger after it.
console.log("displayOrders - orderdata :===", `$scope.odata`);

Below is a screengrab of chrome console where I see all the orders.

[All Orders](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tzNdD.png)

How do I get all these orders into `$scope.odata`?

Comment: Did you already debug this? Put a breakpoint on the line `$scope.odata = snapshot.val();` and see what happens when that gets triggered. `snapshot.val()` is likely very different from what you expect it to be.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just cracked it.
Below is the correct code for getting all orders for a particular user. 
Please refer to the Database structure in the question if you need to.

```
    $scope.odata = {};
    $scope.tempdata =[];
    var fbref = new Firebase("https://xxxxxxx.firebaseio.com/");
    var ordersRef = fbref.child("orders");
    var orddataref = fbref.child("profile").child($scope.cart.userkey).child("orders");
        orddataref.on("child_added", function(snap) {
           ordersRef.child(snap.key()).once("value", function(snapshot){
              $scope.tempdata.push(JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(snapshot.val())));
            }); 
        });
$scope.odata = $scope.tempdata;
```

Since I am a newbie, if anyone has a better solution, please suggest.
@Frank, thank you for pointing to the right path.